# for inside another for is executed just once

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following code to create all possible intervals between two dates:

```js
var minStart = new Date(2019, 10, 1);
var maxStart = new Date(2019, 10, 3);
var minStop = new Date(2019, 10, 20);
var maxStop = new Date(2019, 10, 22);

for (var i = minStart; i <= maxStart; i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)) {
  for (var v = minStop; v <= maxStop; v.setDate(v.getDate() + 1)) {
    console.log(moment(i).format('DD/MM') + ' - ' + moment(v).format('DD/MM'));
  }
}
```

I am expecting to get the following result:

```
01/11 - 20/11
01/11 - 21/11
01/11 - 22/11
02/11 - 20/11
02/11 - 21/11
02/11 - 22/11
03/11 - 20/11
03/11 - 21/11
03/11 - 22/11
```

but I am getting only:

```
>01/11 - 20/11
>01/11 - 21/11
>01/11 - 22/11
```

I debugged the code by putting more `console.log()` outputs and it turns out, that the inner loop is run only once. Any idea why this is happening?

Here is a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkorber/xeguzhn3/) (without the `moment` library that I am using only for formatting).

Comment: `setDate()` mutates the instance, that's your hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're mutating the objects, at the end of the first outer loop, `minStop` will have the same date as `maxStop`. To address that, use something like this: `var v = new Date(minStop)`

Comment: I tried putting `v = minStop` after the inner loop without success.

Comment: @DaniloKörber `v` is declared as a reference to `minStop`. Modifying `v` with `setDate()` modifies `minStop` as well because _they're the same object_

Comment: @DaniloKörber I've edited my answer to suggest a solution.